# any way to use app script javascript to filter with an additional parameter?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a bunch of stock data and the ticks/symbols on it.
The problem is that I need to filter for a particular symbol (and do it about 90 times), and don't wish to have 90 different filter functions for each tick/symbol, but I see no way to create a filter function and pass in something other than an array to it.
Right now I have:

```
let sheet = combinedSheet.getRange("A2:G3945").getValues();
let sheetFiltered = sheet.filter(filterByTickApple);

let filterByTickApple = function(item) {
     if (item[2] === "AAPL") {return true} else {return false};
}
```

Basically, you can see that I'd have to write 90 separate functions.  What I'd like to do would be something that looks like this:

```
  let sheetFiltered = sheet.filter(filterByTick,"AAPL");

  let filterByTick = function(item, tick) {
      if (item[2] === tick) {return true} else {return false};
  }
```

but I know this is not possible as written (I've tried variations, but no joy). Someone else posted that supposedly, you can put other arguments in, but as per the docs, that's not possible (and I've tried their code - it didn't work)

Any idea for a workaround/hack?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. At that time, In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: you can use indexOf.   array.indexOf[item[2]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the rows including `AAPL` and other values in the column "C".

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, if my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var values = ["AAPL","###",,,]; // Please set the values you want to check.
let sheet = combinedSheet.getRange("A2:G3945").getValues();
let sheetFiltered = sheet.filter(e => values.includes(e[2]));
```

#### References:

- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: That works.  The "values" variable would be a deduped array of all the values in that column (deduped as they occur multiple times), though I'd be looping through them to plop them in other tabs.  I suppose I was overthinking the filter function. Thanks

 in shortened form, it would look like:   let sheetFiltered = sheet.filter(e => e[2]=="AAPL");

Comment: @MC9000 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. For example, when you want to remove the duplicated values from `values`, you can also use `[...new Set(values)]`.